# Singleton class object creating outside the class

Tags: java, singleton

Is there any way to create object outside the class in singleton design pattern?

```
public class Test {
     private Test() {}
     private static final Test t=new Test();

     public static Test getTest() {
        return t;  
     } 
}
```

Comment: If you can create the object outside of its class, you will not be able to ensure/enforce the Singleton Pattern.

Comment: sorry it's public method

Comment: @Keale `Test` constructor is private, so it cannot be created outside the class.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? What do you want to do exactly? What are the reasons for the singleton pattern? Performance? Resources?

Comment: If it is a singleton you want then get it the traditional way.. Why do you want to do this ?

Comment: Okay, I'm confused. OP asks if there is *any way to create object outside the class in singleton design pattern* so I answered that if you create it outside of its class, then Singleton cannot be enforced. Am I wrong?

Comment: Note that it's possible to use reflection to call the private constructor

Answer (score 0):

Although the singleton pattern doesn't really work if you want to do this, I can still tell you what to do. I guess you mean "Get an arbitary instance outside the singleton class". Now you can add the following method:

```
public Test getNewTest (/*You can add parameters if you like*/) {
    return enw Test();
}
```

But this really violates the singleton pattern. You use the singleton pattern because you just want *one* instance of it. But now you can create multiple instance of it!

Comment: This will always create a new instance in the memory

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo but isn't this what the OP wanted?

Comment: singleton means there should be  one object in the app

Comment: I know what singleton means. But apparently the OP doesn't want to follow the rules. So I told him/her how. @DanyalSandeelo

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "outside of the class" but this public access static method will create your object one and only one time.

```
class MySingletonObject {
   private static MySingletonObject instance = null;

   private MySingletonObject() {};

   public static MySingletonObject getInstance() {
       if (instance == null) {
           instance = new MySingletonObject();
       }
       return instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the name singleton it signifies only one object, mainly used to create a jdbc connection.. Where only one connection can be fetched at a time.Making singleton class public i.e. Constructor doesn't make any sense as it can be instantiated via any other class.. That's why a factory method is developed which returns only one object(new one for first time and existed for further attempts).Here you're restricting the instantiation which is the basic rule while developing a singleton class.

Answer (score 0):

A [quick search](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=singleton%20design%20pattern) on Singleton Design Pattern tells us that it is used so that we are sure **that only one instance of a class is created**.

**[Singleton](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton) [Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)** is useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate the actions across the system. The object must also be responsible for creation, initialization, access, and enforcement of this design pattern.

As [Sweeper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5133585/sweeper) [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32557948/2431281), it is possible to create the object outside of its class. If we make this possible, then we will not sure anymore if the class still follows the Singleton Design Pattern. Creating the object outside of its class violates the Design Pattern. It will not be a Singleton anymore.

**TLDR;** Yes, there is a way to create the object outside its class, however it will not be a Singleton anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This is just show that it is possible to create object outside the singleton class, but this would not be according to the singleton pattern:

### Test.java

```
public class Test {
    private Test() {
    }

    private static Test t = null;

    public static Test getTest() {
        if (t == null) {
            synchronized (Test.class) {
                if (t == null) {
                    try {
                        t = Util.createAndGetTest();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(
                                "Exception creating Test object", e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return t;
    }
}
```

### Util.java

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class Util {

    public static Test createAndGetTest() throws NoSuchMethodException,
            InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException,
            InstantiationException {
        Constructor<Test> constructor = Test.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        Test t = constructor.newInstance();
        return t;
    }

}
```

### Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = Test.getTest();

    }
}
```